# Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense not working for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2017, I could just add:
`/// <reference path="../core3/core3.js" />`
to the top of a .js file and IntelliSense would know to look there for functions, listing them when I start typing "$.", and listing their parameters when I selected one.  F12 would also redirect to the function in another file.

I recently got a new computer and installed Visual Studio Pro 2022.  I cannot get IntelliSense to work in 2022 for JS files.  It works for C#. If the JS function is local in that file, it will get the function name, but not its parameters.  F12 will redirect to it.

If the function is in a reference path js file, it will get nothing.  F12 does not work.
Pressing ctrl + shift + space just flashes a "Loading..." for less than 1 second.

I remember having this problem with VS 2019 too, so I just uninstalled it and went back to 2017, that's not an option now as Mainstream support for Visual Studio 2017 ended on April 12, 2022.

I do get partial results with cryptic errors: "IntelliSense is unable to determine the accuracy of this completion item."

[IntelliSense is unable to determine the accuracy of this completion item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Ho3.png)

JSDoc comments ahead of functions are ignored and not displayed /** @description, @param, @return */

I've tried:

- Making sure [Auto List members] and [Parameter Information] are checked in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General.
- added \scripts_references.js file to project
- deleted the .vs folder in the solution and let it rebuild
- installed all sorts of different features in VS I don't need.
- deleted the C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ folder and let it rebuild
- cursing
- using a solution created in VS2017
- creating a new solution in VS2022 - ASP.NET empty web site, then copy in code from previous solution.
- updated VS2022 to the latest version
- restarting computer

Any ideas on how to enable the most basic of Visual Studio features in 2022?

Comment: Side note: I hate VS for anything web development related with the exception of Razor or other MS framework dependent languages. I use VSCode for all web development and love it. It is light weight and can run side by side with VS without worrying about resource contention.

Comment: I have a coworker that uses VSCode, but we pay for pro licenses of Visual Studio.  Shouldn't it's basic features work?!?

Comment: From looking at your screenshot of this warning message `IntelliSense is unable to determine the accuracy of this completion item`, i see you use `$.` to invoke function from reference js file, could you please invoke function by typing `function name` instead of `$.`?  See this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHdQb.png).I type a function name that is from  reference js file and intellisense seems work fine.

Comment: @DouXu-MSFT Typing more gets some results, but not all, and still ignores the jsdoc.
[link] https://imgur.com/UqexAPg

Comment: Have you tried to remove `$.` and typed function name ? Does IntelliSense  work? If i type all function name, i will get the function name and its parameters.

Comment: that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you checked if the path to the core3.js file referenced is correct?